# Select highest 3 scores in each day for every user

Tags: mysql

I have a MYSQL table like this:

```
  id |  userid  |  score  |      datestamp      |
-----------------------------------------------------
  1  |    1     |   5     |  2012-12-06 03:55:16
  2  |    2     |   0,5   |  2012-12-06 04:25:21
  3  |    1     |   7     |  2012-12-06 04:35:33
  4  |    3     |   12    |  2012-12-06 04:55:45
  5  |    2     |   22    |  2012-12-06 05:25:11
  6  |    1     |   16,5  |  2012-12-06 05:55:21
  7  |    1     |   19    |  2012-12-06 13:55:16
  8  |    2     |   8,5   |  2012-12-07 06:27:16
  9  |    2     |   7,5   |  2012-12-07 08:33:16
  10 |    1     |   10    |  2012-12-07 09:25:19
  11 |    1     |   6,5   |  2012-12-07 13:33:16
  12 |    3     |   6     |  2012-12-07 15:45:44
  13 |    2     |   4     |  2012-12-07 16:05:16
  14 |    2     |   34    |  2012-12-07 18:33:55
  15 |    2     |   22    |  2012-12-07 18:42:11
```

I would like to display user scores like this:
if a user on a certain day has more than 3 scores it would get only highest 3, repeat that for every day for this user and then add all days together. I want to display this sum for every user.

EDIT:
So in the example above for user 1 on 06.12. I would add top 3 scores together and ignore 4th score, then add to that number top 3 from the next day and so on. I need that number for every user.

EDIT 2:
Expected output is:

```
  userid |   score  
--------------------
    1    |    59    //19 + 16.5 + 7 (06.12.) + 10 + 6.5 (07.12.)
    2    |    87    //22 + 0.5 (06.12.) + 34 + 22 + 8.5 (07.12.)
    3    |    18    //12 (06.12.) + 6 (07.12.)
```

I hope this is more clear :)

I would really appreciate the help because I am stuck.

Comment: So you want 1st highest scores, 2nd highest scores, 3rd highest scores per year?

Comment: No, I want one score per user, that score is sum of 3 best scores for each day.

Comment: I updated the question with hopefully more clearer explanation of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Simon, can you update your question with the expected output based on the sample data you have provided here?

Comment: I added a couple of records to sample data and added expected output.

Comment: Simon, you are not listing Top 3 scores per each user per day, which is day 1, 3 top scores for user 1, 3 top scores for user 2, so on.. like 3*number of users*number of day...that's the impression your titles gives, at least to me :$ But looking at your expected output, it is clear that you want summed up top 3 scores per user. You have even updated your source data sample.................

Comment: lz Ljubljane : Please take a look at the updated answer with my sample data. That makes things much simpler ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at the following code, if your answer to my comment is `yes` :) Since your data all in 2012, and month of november, I took day.

- [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a856/1) sample

Query:

```
select y.id, y.userid, y.score, y.datestamp 
from (select id, userid, score, datestamp 
      from scores
      group by day(datestamp)) as y    
where (select count(*) 
       from (select id, userid, score, datestamp
             from scores group by day(datestamp)) as x
       where y.score >= x.score
       and y.userid = x.userid
      ) =1 -- Top 3rd, 2nd, 1st    
order by y.score desc
;
```

Results:

```
ID  USERID  SCORE   DATESTAMP
8   2       8.5 December, 07 2012 00:00:00+0000
20  3       6   December, 08 2012 00:00:00+0000
1   1       5   December, 06 2012 00:00:00+0000
```

Based on your latter updates to question.
If you need some per user by year/month/day and then find highest, you may simply add aggregation function like `sum` to the above query. I am reapeating myself, since your sample data is for just one year, there's no point group by year or month. That's why I took day.

```
select y.id, y.userid, y.score, y.datestamp 
from (select id, userid, sum(score) as score,
      datestamp 
from scores
group by userid, day(datestamp)) as y    
where (select count(*) 
from (select id, userid, sum(score) as score
      , datestamp
from scores
group by userid, day(datestamp)) as x
where y.score >= x.score
and y.userid = x.userid
) =1 -- Top 3rd, 2nd, 1st    
order by y.score desc
;
```

Results based on sum:

```
ID  USERID  SCORE   DATESTAMP
1   1       47.5    December, 06 2012 00:00:00+0000
8   2       16      December, 07 2012 00:00:00+0000
20  3       6       December, 08 2012 00:00:00+0000
```

### UPDATED WITH NEW SOURCE DATA SAMPLE

Simon, please take a look at my own sample. As your data was changing, I used mine. 
Here is the reference. I have used pure `ansi` style without any `over partition` or `dense_rank`.
Also note the data I used are getting top 2 not top 3 scores. You can change is accordingly.

**Guess what, the answer is 10 times simpler than the first impression your first data gave....**

### [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce1e3/1)

Query to 1:
-- for top 2 sum by user by each day

```
SELECT userid, sum(Score), datestamp
FROM scores t1
where 2 >=
(SELECT count(*) 
 from scores t2
 where t1.score <= t2.score
 and t1.userid = t2.userid
 and day(t1.datestamp) = day(t2.datestamp)
 order by t2.score desc)
group by userid, datestamp 
;
```

Results for query 1:

```
USERID  SUM(SCORE)  DATESTAMP
1       70      December, 06 2012 00:00:00+0000
1       30      December, 07 2012 00:00:00+0000
2       22      December, 06 2012 00:00:00+0000
2       25      December, 07 2012 00:00:00+0000
3       30      December, 06 2012 00:00:00+0000
3       30      December, 07 2012 00:00:00+0000
```

Final Query:
-- for all two days top 2 sum by user

```
SELECT userid, sum(Score)
FROM scores t1
where 2 >=
(SELECT count(*) 
 from scores t2
 where t1.score <= t2.score
 and t1.userid = t2.userid
 and day(t1.datestamp) = day(t2.datestamp)
 order by t2.score desc)
group by userid
;
```

Final Results:

```
USERID  SUM(SCORE)
1      100
2      47
3      60
```

Here goes a snapshot of direct calculations of data I used.

[image]

Comment: The top 3 scores for userid 1 would sum up to 42.5, not 47.5 - this is a tough nut to crack!

Comment: Thanks @Danny I want to see his expected output still ;)

Comment: I added 5 records to sample data and added expected output. I added changed values to your sample from sqlfiddle but the values are not correct

Comment: Wow, +1 for effort, I will test this but I think this is it :) Thank you.

Comment: Tested and it WORKS. Thank you again for thorough explanation :)

Comment: Well I am glad you got it worked. But one thing to share: answers, guides would come to you pretty fast if you could shoot your question with `create table`, `insert` data statment, proper sample data and expected output :) even better if you could add the reference of SQLFIDDLE after creating/inserting data to your tables. With any query you have tried out at best. So others will know that you have tried. **You data and Expected output makes all the difference.** Good Luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    table1
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY score LIMIT 3) as lr on DATE(lr.datestamp) = DATE(table1.datastamp)
GROUP BY 
    datestamp
```

Comment: Tried this and it does not do what I need.