# limit the number of a field value in search results

Tags: php, mysql

I run real state website, which allows different  users to add their properties.
When someone searches for a specific criteria, we use a select statement along with the specified conditions to select the matched properties, do the paging bit and display the results.

We use a rating algorithm to rate each property and use it to priorities the displayed properties.

A simplified version:

```
name            type      bedrooms           user  score
green house     sale      two bedrooms       alex  6
Blue one        rent      three bedrooms     jack  6
Blue one        sale      three bedrooms     jack  4
gray one        sale      three bedrooms     jack  6
green one       rent      three bedrooms     jack  6
purple one      rent      three bedrooms     jack  6
green one       rent      three bedrooms     jack  6
green one       rent      three bedrooms     gary  6
```

Now the problem is that sometimes a few properties have the same score.  In these cases I don't want properties from one user to dominate a search result page, I want to set a limit to display a maximum of three properties of any given user in a search result page.

In the example, I don't want the properties owned by jack to dominate the first page, and properties of other users go to second page. This would upset other users and create a bad experience for visitors.

If I wanted to show only one property for a given user, I'd use Group by, but I'm not sure what to limit to a larger number ( three for instance).  Is there anything I could do in mysql to achieve this?

EDIT:

Sorry if it wasnt clear enough.

The use field displays the user who added the particular property. A sample query could be

```
SELECT * FROM properties WHERE type = 'sale' LIMIT 5 ORDER BY score
```

The result could be five properties, all added by jack. I want to make sure that no more than thee properties added by a particular user, are included in the results. This way properties added by other users would have a chance to be displayed.

Comment: Can we know some sample inputs and desired outputs? I am confused at the user part, can your search results be filtered by user? If not, do you want the highest 3 scores be fetched by different users on the first page?

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger i think OP wants to fetch maximum 3 records for every user from all records

Comment: Thanks for your input. I edited my question, to clarify things

Answer (score 1):

use DISTINCT in your query something like this example

SELECT DISTINCT column_name,column_name from table;

Comment: using a column_name twice in the distinct query would limit the occurrences to two?

Answer (score 1):

Use DISTINCT it will solve your problem.In a table, a column may contain many duplicate values; and sometimes you only want to list the different (distinct) values.The DISTINCT keyword can be used to return only distinct (different) values. Example
`SELECT DISTINCT user FROM table_name;`

Comment: Wouldn't DISTINCT limit the number of properties added by each user to 1, and not 3?

Answer (score 1):

try with this and change string `your_table` with your table name

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    `your_table`
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 3) as lr on lr.user = `your_table`.user
GROUP BY 
    user
```

[reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763855/select-highest-3-scores-in-each-day-for-every-user)

**UPDATE 2**

if you want to order by your score you can use

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    `your_table`
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM `your_table` ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 3) as lr on lr.user = `your_table`.user
GROUP BY 
    user
```

Comment: I'm just curious, since my table has around 70,000 properties, wouldn't this approach cause serious performance issues?

Comment: that might be slow but if you use pagination you can use limit for it. i think you do not need to show all records of them at once.